# Android CTS on 4.0.3 list device is showing device as unavailable

Tags: android, device, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cts

I am trying to run CTS on Android 4.0.3. In the process i am facing following issue.
Cts-tf > list devices is showing my device state as unavailable. As per CTS manual, this means the device is not responding to adb commands. But the commands works just fine for me when i try to run them manually. I would like to know what all can be the possible cause of device being treated as unavailable. Also if someone can suggest me more pointer to debug the issue further.

Other information.

1. I have verified that all the settings are done as discussed in CTS manual.
2. I am connecting adb using ethernet ( adb connect IP_addr) and not usb.
3. I am running cts on windows host ( in case this matters).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem under Linux and found it is related to the environment variable ANDROID_SERIAL. If ANDROID_SERIAL is not set or is different from the serial of the device to be tested, the device will show up as "Unavailable"

This behavior doesn't make much sense, as CTS allows to distribute the tests on several devices (--shards) and also has an option to specify the serial number of the device to test

Comment: I tried ur suggestion but it didn's work for me. I have an observation. getprop -> ro.serialno is blank in my case. Can that be an issue?

Comment: Got solution to this issue. system folder was not in root (/). Hence the error